# HTML::TableExtract with a table inside of a table

Tags: perl, html-tableextract

I have a small script that I am using to manipulate the code from a remote URL (code is separate). The manual page for HTML::TableExtract has the following code section relating to doing a table-in-a-table extract, ie

```
$te = new HTML::TableExtract
      (
       headers => [qw(Summary Region)],
       chain   => [
                   { depth => 0, count => 2 },
                   { headers => [qw(Part Qty Cost)] }
                  ],
      );
```

My code contains this, ie:

```
use HTML::TableExtract;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $te = new HTML::TableExtract
      (
       headers => [qw(Incident Date Time Location Description)],
       chain   => [
                   { depth => 0, count => 2 },
                   { headers => [qw(Unit DIS ENR ONS LEF ARR BUS REM COM)] }
                  ],
      );

$te->parse_file('data.html');
```

However, running it gives me this:

```
Can't locate object method "chain" via package "HTML::TableExtract" at /usr/lib/perl5/HTML/Parser.pm line 80.
```

Is there something I'm missing? (If anyone has a better way to extract a table from within a table (while printing information from both I'm all ears)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see any document about `chain` method in [the doc](http://search.cpan.org/~msisk/HTML-TableExtract-2.11/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm) of `HTML::TableExtract`. Maybe you're using an expired version?

But according to the doc, you could do this using the `depth` and `count` attributes:

```
$te = HTML::TableExtract->new( 
                              headers => [qw(Unit DIS ENR ONS LEF ARR BUS REM COM)], 
                              depth => 1, 
                              count => 1 
                             );
$te->parse($html_string);
```

> depth: Specify how embedded in other tables your tables of interest
>   should be. Top-level tables in the HTML document have a depth of 0,
>   tables within top-level tables have a depth of 1, and so on.
>
> count: Specify which table within each depth you are interested in,
>   beginning with 0.

In your case `depth` and `count` should be both 1.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man3/HTML::TableExtract.3pm.html was the one I was referring to, it's OLD and outdated (and it's the first one that shows up on a google search for 'chain' )

Comment: @NoWay So which version of this module did you install, the outdated one or the one on CPAN? It it's the latter you could follow the new doc, using `depth` and `count` attributes to find your nested table of interest.

Comment: I installed the latest one from CPAN via 'cpan install HTML::TableExtract' which is 2.xx or so. Sorry for the confusion, didn't realize chain was changed to depth.